# Jest async componentDidMount acceptance test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, acceptance-testing

My component is the following:

```
export default class Link extends React.Component {
  state = { url: "" };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const result = await MyUrlService.getUrl(this.props.urlId);
    this.setState({
      url: result
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.url && (
        <a href={this.state.url}>
          {this.props.text}
        </a>
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I've unit tested `Link.jsx` and `MyUrlService.js` covering them with tests (green I should say!).

However, I would like to have an acceptance test to detect that my Link component, after `componentDidMount`, the response from `MyUrlService.getUrl` is in the `href` prop.

Anyhow, I haven't been able to await for the re-render of the component after setting the state in `async componentDidMount`.
I've tried flushing promises, mounting then flushing promises, mounting, awaiting mounting, all to no luck.

I've been able to successfully use `enzyme-async-helpers`, but hooking to the state doesn't seem the right thing to do.

Here's the spec file for the acceptance test

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import Link from "../../src/components/Link";

describe("link component", () => {
    describe("given valid url Id", () => {
      const flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));

      const mountAndFlush = async (urlId) => {
        const wrapper = mount(<Link urlId={urlId} text={"whatever text} />);
        await flushPromises();
        return wrapper;
      };
      it("should include url from url service", async () => {
        const component = await mountAndFlush("main-landing-page");

        // const component = mount(<Link mpvId="standardBusinessCards" linkType="product" />);
        expect(component.find("a").props().href).toEqual("/landing-page/main");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: do you mock `MyUrlService.getUrl` or use real call to API?

Comment: Since it's an acceptance test, I don't mock anything, so I use real call to API

Comment: actually [waitForElement](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-async-helpers#waitforelement) from `enzyme-async-helpers` looks like right move for me. How did you try using that?

Comment: Using `enzyme-async-helpers` did pass the test to green, but I would expect that enzyme has a better way of testing this

Comment: nope, enzyme does not have anything like `waitForElement`, it's rather lib for unit-testing when you mock everything async

Answer (score 0):

Before return the wrapper you should update the wrapper (**wrapper.update();**).

Replace

```
await flushPromises();
return wrapper;
```

with

```
await flushPromises();
wrapper.update();
return wrapper;
```